# убрать активный класс при клике на активный элемент

Tags: typescript, angular

Задача: убрать активный класс при клике на активный элемент

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csnunr?file=app/app.component.ts

С angular-8 только начинаю - помогите, плиз!

Comment: this.activeItem = (this.activeItem === item) ? null : item;

Comment: Спасибо огромное